# conflict with variable "title" in Laravel and Slider Revolution

Tags: php, laravel, revolution-slider

I'm using Laravel 6.5 and I inserted the Slider Revolution in my blade template.

I'm getting the message and I don't know how to resolve it:

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Use of undefined constant title - assumed 'title' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

The laravel tells me that the line below is giving the problem:

```
tmp:'<span class="tp-bullet-img-wrap">  <span class="tp-bullet-image"></span></span><span class="tp-bullet-title">{{title}}</span>'
```

Has anyone experienced this problem and knows how to solve it?

I thank you for your help.

Comment: You have to use like `{{$title}}` like this. Instead it return error.

Comment: @GhanuBha I did what you suggested, then I lose the information from Slider Revolution. I keep the slider titles blank / empty.

Comment: Is there `$title` contain empty value ?

Comment: No. In code JS Revolution:   if (li.data('title') !== undefined) obj.params.push({from:RegExp("\\{\\{title\\}\\}","g"), to:li.data("title")})

Comment: `{{ $var }}` echoes `$var` unescaped, you can do that easily `@{{title}}`

Comment: @STA Now it worked perfectly

Comment: how do I mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `{{ $var }}` echoes `$var` **unescaped**.
> `@` **escapes** the curly brace for blade compilation.

If you need to display a string that is wrapped in curly braces, you may escape the blade behavior by prefixing your text with an **@** symbol :

```
 @{{title}}
```

See the official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks)